# How to execute VBS?

Tags: vbscript, vb6

I found how to make this

[Download_Example](http://www.vb-helper.com/HowTo/howto_execute_vbscript.zip%22Download_Example%22)

I have a question about how to make execute VBS in vb6 (VBS haves form3 (from vb6 project .)show)

I made a dialog with Microsoft common dialog control 6.0

```
CommonDialog1.Filter = "File (*.vbs)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*"
CommonDialog1.DefaultExt = "vbs"
CommonDialog1.DialogTitle = "Select File"
CommonDialog1.ShowOpen
```

The `FileName` property gives you the variable you need to use

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question correctly, but have a look at how to use the [Microsoft Script Control](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?510292-Execute-VB6-functions-from-a-textbox) to execute VBScript code **within** your application, i.e. code in a textbox control. If you just want to execute the selected VBScript file as a _separate process_, use VB's [Shell function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/shell-function) instead.

Comment: The link does not work.  Please copy and paste your code for the solution.

Comment: eglease im not him i found on internet, ask using the email on the 404 page and i put this years ago

Answer (score 1):

A work-around might be just executing the script using `Shell`.

```
Shell "wscript.exe c:\myscript.vbs", vbNormalFocus
```

```
Shell "wscript.exe " & CommonDialog1.FileName, vbNormalFocus
```

See Microsoft's [wscript documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/wscript).

`vbNormalFocus` is there to restore focus to your vb6 program.  It is optional but you probably want it. See [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/shell-function).

Comment: but wscript is fine but i need to open internal forms in vbscript (form3.show)

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure I understand.  You have a VB6 program and a VBScript, correct?  You want to run the VBScript from your VB6 application, correct?  By form, do you mean the VB6 dialog Form (https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Hiding_and_Showing_Forms_in_Visual_Basic)?

Comment: Did I understand it backwards and you want to open a VB6 program from VBScript?

Comment: Will this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67223096/reading-a-dll-or-vb6-file-from-vbscript?

Comment: #eglease no open vb6 in vbscript i need open vbscript in vb6

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to run a VBScript from your VB6 app to open a dialog in the VB6 app.

```
VB6 -> VBScript -> Same VB6
```

You cannot do this with `Shell` since it runs the script as a separate process. The Script does not know what `Form3` is because it is a component of the VB6 app and would not exist as a separate entity once the app is compiled.

**Edit:**  Looks like what you want to do is possible but with [Microsoft Script Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2000/june/visual-programmer-add-scripting-to-your-apps-with-microsoft-scriptcontrol).  [Here](http://www.thescarms.com/VBasic/Scripting.aspx) [are](https://www.toolbox.com/tech/programming/question/pass-variable-from-visual-basic-form-to-external-vbs-120607/) a [few](https://flylib.com/books/en/1.492.1/adding_vbscript_to_your_vb_applications.html) [examples](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?679851-VB6-ScriptData-Another-Script-Control-Example).  Thank you [@GSerg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11683/gserg) for pointing this out.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21559775/vbscript-to-open-a-dialog-to-select-a-filepath) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21605141/opening-form-from-other-project-vb6?rq=1) might be used as a work-around but I don't think it is the right way to go.

Go back to your requirements.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  There has to be a better way.

Comment: You easily can with Microsoft Script Control as noted earlier in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69058579/vb6-how-to-execute-vbs-i-add-form3-show-to-vbs-but-form3-come-from-vb6-project/69104326#comment122086916_69058579). Just give the script some object of yours, such as your `Forms` collection, with `AddObject`, and it then can operate on it.

Comment: @GSerg This should be the answer.  I am still not sure why you would want to do that but it does answer the question.